# Trigger to enforce constraint that employee never change department

Tags: oracle, oracle11g, triggers

Suppose I have following schema :

```
DEPARTMENT (DepartmentName, BudgetCode, OfficeNumber, Phone)
EMPLOYEE (EmployeeNumber, FirstName, LastName, Department, Phone, Email)
```

Now I need to write a trigger that enforce the constraint that an employee can never change his or her department.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER department_fixed
BEFORE UPDATE ON EMPLOYEE
FOR EACH ROW
   WHEN (old.Department is not null)
BEGIN
    dbms_output.put('You can not change department');
END;
/
```

Is this right way to write this oracle trigger or am missing something ?
Also please help me to write a trigger to allow the deletion of a department if it only has one employee. Assign the last employee to the Human Resources department.

Comment: How this fails ? Did you tried it ? Also, the dbms_output is not really a regular way to inform user that he did something wrong.

Comment: @tvm Thats what am asking , whats the right way. And whats trigger for second one ?

Answer (score 0):

You're close. What this trigger is going to do is for every update of the EMPLOYEE table, it's going to check the original department and if it's not null, it will print something to the screen. I'm assuming you're allowing updates for other fields, right? So my trigger would look like this:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER EMPLOYEE_BUR
BEFORE UPDATE ON EMPLOYEE
FOR EACH ROW
DECLARE

DEPT_EXCEPTION EXCEPTION; --Declare the exception
PRAGMA EXCEPTION_INIT(DEPT_EXCEPTION, -20002);
L_COUNT NUMBER

BEGIN
SELECT COUNT(*) INTO L_COUNT FROM DEPARTMENT D
WHERE D.DEPARTMENT=:OLD.DEPARTMENT;

IF (:OLD.DEPARTMENT <> :NEW.DEPARTMENT) AND (L_COUNT > 0) THEN
     RAISE DEPT_EXCEPTION;
END IF;
END;
```

.. and then I handle the DEPT_EXCEPTION in my calling procedure. You must either raise an exception -OR- do something with :NEW.DEPARTMENT or else the trigger will finish and the update statement will complete. The "EMPLOYEE_BUR" name is more for best practices, this way you know what it is. "BUR" - "Before Update for each Row"

For the second part, you could have a trigger on DEPARTMENT that fires before the delete to confirm deletion, then one after to reassign the employee:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER DEPARTMENT_BDR
BEFORE DELETE ON DEPARTMENT
FOR EACH ROW
DECLARE

DEPT_COUNT_EXCEPTION EXCEPTION;
PRAGMA EXCEPTION_INIT(DEPT_COUNT_EXCEPTION, -20003);
L_COUNT NUMBER;

BEGIN

SELECT COUNT(*) INTO L_COUNT FROM EMPLOYEE E
WHERE E.DEPARTMENT=:OLD.DEPARTMENT;

IF (L_COUNT > 1 ) THEN
    RAISE DEPT_COUNT_EXCEPTION;
END IF;
END;
```

Then...

```
 CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER DEPARTMENT_ADR
 AFTER DELETE ON DEPARTMENT
 FOR EACH ROW

 BEGIN
    UPDATE EMPLOYEE
    SET DEPARTMENT='HR'
    WHERE EMPLOYEE=:OLD.EMPLOYEE;
 END;
```

So this way, if you're deleting a Department with more than one employee, trigger 2 fires and raises an exception so trigger 3 will not. If trigger 2 completes fine, then trigger 3 will fire which re-assigns the employee. If the delete statement completed, then the update will be allowed since there is no former department.

Comment: What about second query ? I am having problem framing it :(

Comment: My apologies! I didn't see that part I was focused on the code. I've edited for a potential solution. :)

Comment: Oh Thats great :) Last one I need to write a system of triggers to enforce the M-M relationship. Assuming that departments with only one employee can be deleted. and also need to assign the last employee in a department to Human Resources.